# how to organize website with php and include statement

Tags: php, html, web

I'm trying to learn website creation with php and mysql, and I'm getting abit confused with concept of template.

My book tells me to index.php to include most of php codes, and there is a statement to output output.html.php.

Example:

```
<?php
 try
  {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ijdb', 'ijdbuser', 'mypassword');
  }
 catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
  }
```

Then the book tells me to  create output.html.php file that includes simple php that includes $output value. I'm abit confused with this concept, because I'm assuming the instructor included the extention html thinking we need to include html in the file.... However, isn't it easier to include html in the index file, and have a simple php code to output the files that include complex php code?

I would like to understand how website code should be organized...

thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the name of the file, the only thing matter here is `.php`, you can name it anything you want say, `myname.php `with a required `echo` statement to display message in it.  You interpreted it correct that the intructor wants reader to understand that it may contain the HTML into it.

Comment: @subin please read about language constructs in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to start with a framework like codeigniter.
if you can work with you understand the organization of files. and MVC structure.

there are also other more difficult framework like symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Your out.html.php (the name really doesn't matter) can be purely HTML if you'd like.

Just write your HTML, don't use any  tags, and it will still work.

The point is that you CAN write some PHP code into if if you need (which in real life you usually do).